# Getting specific data from list of dictionaries in Python using dot notation

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dictionaries and strings like so:

```
    listDict = [{'id':1,'other':2}, {'id':3,'other':4}, 
                {'name':'Some name','other':6}, 'some string']
```

I want a list of all the ids (or other attributes) from the dictionaries via dot operator. So, from the given list I would get the list:

```
listDict.id
[1,3]

listDict.other
[2,4,6]

listDict.name
['Some name']
```

Thanks

Comment: Why?  That's not proper Python syntax.  What's the point?

Comment: @S. Lott: There is no syntactic error in the presented code, and it is easily possible to implement such a type by various techniques (e.g. properties or customized attribute access through `.__getattr__()`).

Comment: @lunaryorn:  All true.  But why?  What's the use case for this?  Why not create a class or a named tuple?  Why do this with dictionaries?

Comment: @S. Lott: How am I supposed to know, *why* the OP would want to do this, and what his use case is?  I've only pointed how, that it can be done, if one wants to, and in proper standard Python syntax. :)

Answer (score 4):

python doesn't work this way. you'd have to redefine your `listDict`. the built-in list type doesn't support such access. the simpler way is just to get the new lists like this:

```
>>> ids = [d['id'] for d in listDict if isinstance(d, dict) and 'id' in d]
>>> ids
[1, 3]
```

P.S. your data structure seems to be awfully heterogeneous. if you explain what you're trying to do, a better solution can be found.

Answer (score 3):

To do that, you'd need to create a class based on list:

```
    class ListDict(list):
       def __init__(self, listofD=None):
          if listofD is not None:
             for d in listofD:
                self.append(d)

       def __getattr__(self, attr):
          res = []
          for d in self:
             if attr in d:
                res.append(d[attr])
          return res

    if __name__ == "__main__":
       z = ListDict([{'id':1, 'other':2}, {'id':3,'other':4},
                    {'name':"some name", 'other':6}, 'some string'])
       print z.id
       print z.other

   print z.name
```